# How to add properties to DOM elements via $.map

Tags: jquery

Hmmm... What am I doing wrong here?

I have a html structure like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <ul> ... </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <ul> ... </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <ul> ... </ul>
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

I would like to add the "target list" as a property to all links

```
var $links = $('a');

$.map($links, function(link, i){
  link.$targetList = $(link).next();
});

$links.click(function() {
  console.log($(this).$targetList);
});
```

A click, however, returns "undefined"

Comment: You added it to the dom element, not the jQuery object. `this.$targetList`

Comment: @KevinB could you write a piece of working code please? I have been wrestling with that exact aspect for some time. DOM element vs jQuery object.

Comment: I tested it in the console of this very page, simply changing `$(this)` to `this` and `click` to `each` (so that i wouldn't have to click a link) and it worked for me. http://pastebin.com/1GwtFaWs

Comment: Im not using $(this) anywhere?

Comment: The second from the last line in your snippet above, the one line inside the click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.map` wasn't intended to add properties, it builds an array map of whatever you pass back.

jQuery has a `data()` method to attach arbitrary data to jQuery objects, you can even store another element in `data()` (which is what `next()` gets, the next element in the DOM) :

```
var $links = $('a');

$links.each(function(_, link) {
    $(link).data('targetList', $(link).next());
});

$links.click(function() {
    console.log( $(this).data('targetList') );
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jL29H/)

Comment: Any reason why you are using $(link) instead of $(this) ?

Comment: @tolborg - not really, both would work, but as the element is passed as a parameter in each() I tend to use that !

Answer (score 1):

Rather than accessing the property on the jQuery collection, you need to access it on the dom node.

```
var $links = $('a');

$.map($links, function(link, i){
  link.$targetList = $(link).next();
});

$links.click(function() {
  console.log(this.$targetList);/*This is what i changed*/
});
```

though i probably would have stored that data using the .data method as suggested by adeneo.